# Mouse Scroll Down in eclipse not working

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

so eclipse was working fine a couple of days ago
then I updated the android sdk, android ADT....

after this the mouse scroll down wheel doesn't work anymore. 
It works on everything else...but on eclipse (no matter what windows/preference/etc) I open it just doesn't work

anyone know where I should look to fix this.

greatly appreciate the help!!

LATER: after re-installing eclipse and adt it works...

Comment: I can confirm that I have the same issue as well. Haven't tried installing another clean eclipse to see if the problem disapeared, or that the problem is only with the Android SDK packaged eclipse.

Comment: you can vote up my question....

Comment: I just read the "Later" part: Was is a complete reinstallation of the Android SDK from google? Or did you seperately install eclipse and then added the adt plugin afterwards?

Comment: delete eclipse, delete everything except java....

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen Preferences in Eclipse, where you can disable the mouse scroller. I would suggest you to install new eclipse with the same android sdk and see if there the same occurs.

Comment: I didn't want to go through the trouble of installing a new eclipse....maybe some quick fix exists..

Comment: You can just try the new installation with the SDK, so that you will know, that the problem is from the Android Plugin.